# Notifications in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My notification was well displayed when I had this in my index.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id = "notifications">
        <div class= "notification">
            <div class="left">
                <div class="icon">&#x2713;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <h2>Titre</h2>
                <p>Une description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to put this in a jQuery script named jquery.notif.js

```
(function($){

    $.fn.notif = function(options){

        var options = $.extend({
            html : '        <div class= "notification">\
            <div class="left">\
                <div class="icon">&#x2713;</div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="right">\
                <h2>Titre</h2>\
                <p>Une description</p>\
            </div>\
        </div>'
        }, options);    

        console.log(options);

        return this.each(function(){

            MyFutureCode

        })

    }

    $('body').notif({title:'Mon titre', content:'Mon contenu', icon:'&#x2713;'})

})(jQuery);
```

I also changed the index.html to add those lines

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.notif.js"></script>
```

But nothing appear on the screen. I tried to `console.log(options)` and it works. I have my `Object`

Comment: because you do nothing with `options` ? also make sure that the DOM is loaded before calling `$('body').notif`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the html content to the element on which it is called on

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.notif = function(opts) {

    var options = $.extend({
      title: 'Titre',
      content: '',
      icon: '&#x2713;'
    }, opts);


    var html = options.html || '<div class= "notification">\
            <div class="left">\
                <div class="icon">' + options.icon + '</div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="right">\
                <h2>' + options.title + '</h2>\
                <p>' + options.content + '</p>\
            </div>\
        </div>';

    this.append(html); //or preprend

    return this.each(function() {

      //MyFutureCode

    })

  }

  $('body').notif({
    title: 'Mon titre',
    content: 'Mon contenu',
    icon: '&#x2713;'
  })

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you also have to make use of your options (tite, content and icon). They aren't used yet.